# jQuery in Ubuntu not working, but on windows its fine

Tags: jquery

I have this simple jQuery code

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#test').attr('value','hello world');
    $('#test1').text('hello world');
    });
```

And the div / textbox

```
<input type="text" id="test" value="">
<div id="test1" style="width:100px; height:100px;">xxx</div>
```

Any reasons to why it is not working fine.  There are no javascript errors too.

[update-1]
**Making his more easier, jquery does not work on ubuntu at all**

[update-2] html inline

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title> 
<script language="javascript" src="jquery-1.5.min.js"  type="text/javascript"></script> 

<script type="type/javascript"> 

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#test').attr('val','hello world');
    $('#test1').text('hello world');
    });

</script> 

</head>

<body> 
<input type="text" id="test" value="">
<div id="test1" style="width:100px; height:100px;">xxx</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Thanks
Jean

Comment: Which browsers is it working in and not working in? Ubuntu is not a browser.

Comment: What browser are you using in Ubuntu?

Comment: Looks fine to me - what browser(s)? Is this in the same browser(s) and version(s) on win/lin?

Comment: You beat me to it, @Mark. Yes... more info would certainly be helpful.

Comment: This is unrelated to your problem but why use $('#test').attr('value','hello world'); when you can use $('#test').val('hello world');

Comment: @mark exactly which is why i titled it precisely ubuntu and windows

Comment: updated the question, jquery does not work at all

Comment: Ubuntu and Windows are *operating systems*. Chrome, Firefox, IE, Opera, Safari, etc, are *browsers*. Compatability roblems on a web page are almost always related to the browser, and not the operating system. I don't know what problem you are having, but JQuery works perfectly fine on Ubuntu.

Comment: @peter yes it works fine, I am not sure why its not working now..any ideas, its working on fedora and windows7 fine, not on ubuntu!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tried this under Ubuntu 10.04, and Firefox 3.6.12, and it works fine:

```
<html>
<head>

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.5.2.min.js"></script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#test').attr('value','hello world');
    $('#test1').text('hello world');
    });

</script>
</head>

<body>


<input type="text" id="test" value="">
<div id="test1" style="width:100px; height:100px;">xxx</div>

</body>

</html>
```

Notice I changed `$('#test').attr('val','hello world');` to `$('#test').attr('value','hello world');`

I hope that helps.

Comment: thanks the issue was in my code -> "type/javascript" not text/javascript",

Answer (score 1):

I agree with others that the problem is the browser (or, possibly, the setup of the browser), and not Ubuntu itself. You should check global settings (of the browser) and start narrowing down the problem. This is particularly true if even the simplest jQuery isn't working.

1. First thing first - make sure JavaScript works. Is it enabled in the Chrome installation on your Ubuntu machine?
2. Is it only your own site that you are having problems? If you try to visit Stackoverflow on your Ubuntu machine, for example, does the JavaScript work properly there?
3. If it is only your website, is the website being run from a server local to the machine? If so, is it a permissions problem? Are you sure you're actually retrieving the jQuery library? One way to test this is to use the [Google CDN libraries](http://code.google.com/apis/libraries/devguide.html). Chrome's developer tools (Ctrl + Shift + I) can provide more detail as to what is and is not being retrieved.

Basically when you have a problem like this (particularly if everybody is telling you that your code works), you need to start narrowing down the scope of the problem. Start with the obvious and work your way down from there.